# How to get the ID/numerical order of shape draw on Google map by each color

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am developing an app working base on Google map API javascript. That is an example of draw geometry on google map. I reference based on the following code:
https://gist.github.com/mhewedy/836d88158b8cdc24494fb5f8b402dd53

Beside, I would like to count the numerical order/ID of each shape was drawn in each color, especially the rectangle.

I have reference this example Google map developer [Marker Labels](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-labels).  But I'm still wrong.

Please help me how to solve this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/drawing/drawing-tools.html -->
<!-- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox -->
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Drawing Tools (B)</title>
    <!-- NOTE: two libraries to load are comma-separated; otherwise last mention of the query string arg overwrites the previous -->
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3.21.5a&libraries=drawing&signed_in=true&libraries=places,drawing"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      #map, html, body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
      }
      #panel {
        width: 200px;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 13px;
        float: right;
        margin: 10px;
      }
      #color-palette {
        clear: both;
      }
      .color-button {
        width: 14px;
        height: 14px;
        font-size: 0;
        margin: 2px;
        float: left;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      #delete-button {
        margin-top: 5px;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var drawingManager;
      var selectedShape;
      var colors = ['#1E90FF', '#FF1493', '#32CD32', '#FF8C00', '#4B0082'];
      var selectedColor;
      var colorButtons = {};
      function clearSelection() {
        if (selectedShape) {
          if (typeof selectedShape.setEditable == 'function') {
            selectedShape.setEditable(false);
          }
          selectedShape = null;
        }
        curseldiv.innerHTML = "<b>cursel</b>:";
      }
      function updateCurSelText(shape) {
        posstr = "" + selectedShape.position;
        if (typeof selectedShape.position == 'object') {
          posstr = selectedShape.position.toUrlValue();
        }
        pathstr = "" + selectedShape.getPath;
        if (typeof selectedShape.getPath == 'function') {
          pathstr = "[ ";
          for (var i = 0; i < selectedShape.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
            // .toUrlValue(5) limits number of decimals, default is 6 but can do more
            pathstr += selectedShape.getPath().getAt(i).toUrlValue() + " , ";
          }
          pathstr += "]";
        }
        bndstr = "" + selectedShape.getBounds;
        cntstr = "" + selectedShape.getBounds;
        if (typeof selectedShape.getBounds == 'function') {
          var tmpbounds = selectedShape.getBounds();
          cntstr = "" + tmpbounds.getCenter().toUrlValue();
          bndstr = "[NE: " + tmpbounds.getNorthEast().toUrlValue() + " SW: " + tmpbounds.getSouthWest().toUrlValue() + "]";
        }
        cntrstr = "" + selectedShape.getCenter;
        if (typeof selectedShape.getCenter == 'function') {
          cntrstr = "" + selectedShape.getCenter().toUrlValue();
        }
        radstr = "" + selectedShape.getRadius;
        if (typeof selectedShape.getRadius == 'function') {
          radstr = "" + selectedShape.getRadius();
        }
        curseldiv.innerHTML = "<b>cursel</b>: " + selectedShape.type + " " + selectedShape + "; <i>pos</i>: " + posstr + " ; <i>path</i>: " + pathstr + " ; <i>bounds</i>: " + bndstr + " ; <i>Cb</i>: " + cntstr + " ; <i>radius</i>: " + radstr + " ; <i>Cr</i>: " + cntrstr ;
      }
      function setSelection(shape, isNotMarker) {
        clearSelection();
        selectedShape = shape;
        if (isNotMarker)
          shape.setEditable(true);
        selectColor(shape.get('fillColor') || shape.get('strokeColor'));
        updateCurSelText(shape);
      }
      function deleteSelectedShape() {
        if (selectedShape) {
          selectedShape.setMap(null);
        }
      }
      function selectColor(color) {
        selectedColor = color;
        for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; ++i) {
          var currColor = colors[i];
          colorButtons[currColor].style.border = currColor == color ? '2px solid #789' : '2px solid #fff';
        }
        // Retrieves the current options from the drawing manager and replaces the
        // stroke or fill color as appropriate.
        var polylineOptions = drawingManager.get('polylineOptions');
        polylineOptions.strokeColor = color;
        drawingManager.set('polylineOptions', polylineOptions);
        var rectangleOptions = drawingManager.get('rectangleOptions');
        rectangleOptions.fillColor = color;
        drawingManager.set('rectangleOptions', rectangleOptions);
        var circleOptions = drawingManager.get('circleOptions');
        circleOptions.fillColor = color;
        drawingManager.set('circleOptions', circleOptions);
        var polygonOptions = drawingManager.get('polygonOptions');
        polygonOptions.fillColor = color;
        drawingManager.set('polygonOptions', polygonOptions);
      }
      function setSelectedShapeColor(color) {
        if (selectedShape) {
          if (selectedShape.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE) {
            selectedShape.set('strokeColor', color);
          } else {
            selectedShape.set('fillColor', color);
          }
        }
      }
      function makeColorButton(color) {
        var button = document.createElement('span');
        button.className = 'color-button';
        button.style.backgroundColor = color;
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(button, 'click', function() {
          selectColor(color);
          setSelectedShapeColor(color);
        });
        return button;
      }
       function buildColorPalette() {
         var colorPalette = document.getElementById('color-palette');
         for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; ++i) {
           var currColor = colors[i];
           var colorButton = makeColorButton(currColor);
           colorPalette.appendChild(colorButton);
           colorButtons[currColor] = colorButton;
         }
         selectColor(colors[0]);
       }
      /////////////////////////////////////
      var map; //= new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      // these must have global refs too!:
      var placeMarkers = [];
      var input;
      var searchBox;
      var curposdiv;
      var curseldiv;
      function deletePlacesSearchResults() {
        for (var i = 0, marker; marker = placeMarkers[i]; i++) {
          marker.setMap(null);
        }
        placeMarkers = [];
        input.value = ''; // clear the box too
      }
      /////////////////////////////////////
      function initialize() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { //var
          zoom: 12,//10,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.338,114.057),//(22.344, 114.048),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          disableDefaultUI: false,
          zoomControl: true
        });
        curposdiv = document.getElementById('curpos');
        curseldiv = document.getElementById('cursel');
        var polyOptions = {
          strokeWeight: 0,
          fillOpacity: 0.45,
          editable: true
        };
        // Creates a drawing manager attached to the map that allows the user to draw
        // markers, lines, and shapes.
        drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
          drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
          markerOptions: {
            draggable: true,
            editable: true,
          },
          polylineOptions: {
            editable: true
          },
          rectangleOptions: polyOptions,
          circleOptions: polyOptions,
          polygonOptions: polyOptions,
          map: map
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
          //~ if (e.type != google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
            var isNotMarker = (e.type != google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER);
            // Switch back to non-drawing mode after drawing a shape.
            drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
            // Add an event listener that selects the newly-drawn shape when the user
            // mouses down on it.
            var newShape = e.overlay;
            newShape.type = e.type;
            google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function() {
              setSelection(newShape, isNotMarker);
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'drag', function() {
              updateCurSelText(newShape);
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'dragend', function() {
              updateCurSelText(newShape);
            });
            setSelection(newShape, isNotMarker);
          //~ }// end if
        });
        // Clear the current selection when the drawing mode is changed, or when the
        // map is clicked.
        google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'drawingmode_changed', clearSelection);
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', clearSelection);
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('delete-button'), 'click', deleteSelectedShape);
        buildColorPalette();
        //~ initSearch();
        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
         input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */( //var
            document.getElementById('pac-input'));
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(input);
        //
        var DelPlcButDiv = document.createElement('div');
        //~ DelPlcButDiv.style.color = 'rgb(25,25,25)'; // no effect?
        DelPlcButDiv.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
        DelPlcButDiv.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        DelPlcButDiv.innerHTML = 'DEL';
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(DelPlcButDiv);
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(DelPlcButDiv, 'click', deletePlacesSearchResults);
        searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox( //var
          /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(input));
        // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
        // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
        google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
          var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
          if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
          }
          for (var i = 0, marker; marker = placeMarkers[i]; i++) {
            marker.setMap(null);
          }
          // For each place, get the icon, place name, and location.
          placeMarkers = [];
          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
            var image = {
              url: place.icon,
              size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
            };
            // Create a marker for each place.
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              icon: image,
              title: place.name,
              position: place.geometry.location
            });
            placeMarkers.push(marker);
            bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
          }
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
        // Bias the SearchBox results towards places that are within the bounds of the
        // current map's viewport.
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
          var bounds = map.getBounds();
          searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
          curposdiv.innerHTML = "<b>curpos</b> Z: " + map.getZoom() + " C: " + map.getCenter().toUrlValue();
        }); //////////////////////
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="panel">
      <div id="color-palette"></div>
      <div>
        <button id="delete-button">Delete Selected Shape</button>
      </div>
    <div id="curpos"></div>
    <div id="cursel"></div>
    <div id="note"><small>Note: markers can be selected, but are not graphically indicated; can be deleted, but cannot have their color changed.</small></div>
    </div>
    <input id="pac-input" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    <div id="map">A</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

After 1 week, I solved myself, here is the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/drawing/drawing-tools.html -->
<!-- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox 
https://gist.github.com/mhewedy/836d88158b8cdc24494fb5f8b402dd53 -->
<html>

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Draw test</title>
    <!-- NOTE: two libraries to load are comma-separated; otherwise last mention of the query string arg overwrites the previous -->
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3.21.5a&libraries=drawing&signed_in=true&libraries=places,drawing"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      #map, html, body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
      }
      #panel {
        width: 150px;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 13px;
        float: right;
        margin: 10px;
      }
      #color-palette {
        clear: both;
      }
      .color-button {
        width: 14px;    
        height: 14px;
        font-size: 0;
        margin: 2px;
        float: left;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      #delete-button {
        margin-top: 5px;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var drawingManager;
      var selectedShape;
      var colors = ['#1E90FF', '#FF0000'];
        var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        var labelIndex = 0;
      var selectedColor;
      var colorButtons = {};
      var counterDomain = 0;
      var counterRelease = 0;

      
      

      
      
      function updateCurSelText(shape) {
        posstr = "" + selectedShape.position;
        if (typeof selectedShape.position == 'object') {
          posstr = selectedShape.position.toUrlValue();
        }
        
        pathstr = "" + selectedShape.getPath;
        if (typeof selectedShape.getPath == 'function') {
          pathstr = "[ ";
          for (var i = 0; i < selectedShape.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
            // .toUrlValue(5) limits number of decimals, default is 6 but can do more
            pathstr += selectedShape.getPath().getAt(i).toUrlValue() + " , ";
          }
          pathstr += "]";
        }
        
        bndstr = "" + selectedShape.getBounds;

        cntstr = "" + selectedShape.getCenter;


        
        
        if (typeof selectedShape.getBounds == 'function')  {

          var tmpbounds = selectedShape.getBounds();
          cntstr = "" + tmpbounds.getCenter().toUrlValue();
          bndstr = "NE: " + tmpbounds.getNorthEast().toUrlValue() + ' <br />'+
          "SW: "+ tmpbounds.getSouthWest().toUrlValue()+' <br />'+
//           "i = "+selectedShape.getElementById++ ;
          "i = "+labelIndex++ % labels.length ;
//           "i = "+selectedShape.getCenter().toUrlValue() ;


        
        var ne = selectedShape.getBounds().getNorthEast();
        var sw = selectedShape.getBounds().getSouthWest();
if (selectedColor == colors[0]){

                var contentString = '<b>Blue Domain-'+counterDomain+'-Lat/Long: </b><br />' +
                      'Center: '+(ne.lat()+sw.lat())/2 + ' , ' + (ne.lng()+sw.lng())/2 +' <br />'+
                      'North-East-corner: '+ ne.lat() + ' , ' + ne.lng() + ' <br />';
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
        infoWindow.setPosition(ne);
     infoWindow.open(map);
        }
        
        
        
        else {

        var contentString = '<b>Red Domain-'+counterRelease+'-Lat/Long: </b><br />' +
                      'Center: '+(ne.lat()+sw.lat())/2 + ' , ' + (ne.lng()+sw.lng())/2 +' <br />'+
                      'North-East-corner: '+ ne.lat() + ' , ' + ne.lng() + ' <br />';
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
        infoWindow.setPosition(ne);
     infoWindow.open(map);
        
        }
        

        }

       
//         curseldiv.innerHTML = bndstr   ;
//         curseldiv.innerHTML = contentString   ;



      }

      
    function deleteInfowindow(infoWindow){
    
        infoWindow.close();
    }
    
    
    
      function clearSelection() {
        if (selectedShape) {
          if (typeof selectedShape.setEditable == 'function') {
            selectedShape.setEditable(false);
          }
          
          selectedShape = null;
        }
      }
      
      
      function setSelection(shape, isNotMarker) {
        clearSelection();
        selectedShape = shape;
        if (isNotMarker)
          shape.setEditable(true);
        selectColor(shape.get('fillColor') || shape.get('strokeColor'));
        updateCurSelText(shape);
        
      }
      
      
      function deleteSelectedShape() {
              deleteInfowindow(infoWindow);
        if (selectedColor == colors[0]){
            if (selectedShape) {
                selectedShape.setMap(null);
                counterDomain = counterDomain -1;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (selectedShape) {
                selectedShape.setMap(null);
                counterRelease = counterRelease -1;
            }
        }
        
      }
      
      
      function selectColor(color) {
        selectedColor = color;
        for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; ++i) {
          var currColor = colors[i];
          colorButtons[currColor].style.border = currColor == color ? '2px solid #789' : '2px solid #fff';
        }
        // Retrieves the current options from the drawing manager and replaces the
        // stroke or fill color as appropriate.

        var rectangleOptions = drawingManager.get('rectangleOptions');
        rectangleOptions.fillColor = color;
        drawingManager.set('rectangleOptions', rectangleOptions);

      }
      
      function setSelectedShapeColor(color) {
        if (selectedShape) {
          if (selectedShape.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE) {
            selectedShape.set('strokeColor', color);
          } else {
            selectedShape.set('fillColor', color);
          }
        }
      }
      
      function makeColorButton(color) {
        var button = document.createElement('span');
        button.className = 'color-button';
        button.style.backgroundColor = color;
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(button, 'click', function() {
          selectColor(color);
          setSelectedShapeColor(color);
        });
        return button;
      }
      
      function buildColorPalette() {
         var colorPalette = document.getElementById('color-palette');
         for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; ++i) {
           var currColor = colors[i];
           var colorButton = makeColorButton(currColor);
           colorPalette.appendChild(colorButton);
           colorButtons[currColor] = colorButton;
         }
         selectColor(colors[0]);
       }
       
      /////////////////////////////////////
      var map; //= new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      // these must have global refs too!:
      var placeMarkers = [];
      var input;
      var curposdiv;
      var curseldiv;
 
      var infoWindow;
      
      

      
      
      
      function initialize() {
      
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { //var
          zoom: 6,//10,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(18.59590640319714,105.37530464062493),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          disableDefaultUI: false,
          zoomControl: true
        });
        curposdiv = document.getElementById('curpos');
        curseldiv = document.getElementById('cursel');

        var polyOptions = {
          strokeWeight: 2.0,
          fillOpacity: 0.35,
          editable: true          
        };
        // Creates a drawing manager attached to the map that allows the user to draw
        // markers, lines, and shapes.

        drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        
          drawingControl: true,

          drawingControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
            drawingModes: ['rectangle'],
          },

          label: labels[labelIndex++ % labels.length],
//           label: labels[labelIndex++],
//           label: labelIndex++,
          rectangleOptions: polyOptions,
          map: map,
//                         selectedShape.setMap(map),
//                   selectedShape.addListener('bounds_changed', showNewRect),
//         infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),

         }
        );
        

             
        
        
        google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
            var isNotMarker = (e.type != google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER);
            // Switch back to non-drawing mode after drawing a shape.
            drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
            // Add an event listener that selects the newly-drawn shape when the user
            // mouses down on it.
            var newShape = e.overlay;
            newShape.type = e.type;
            if (selectedColor == colors[0]){
                counterDomain=counterDomain+1;
            }
            else{
                counterRelease = counterRelease+1;
            }
            

//             google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'drag', function() {
//               updateCurSelText(newShape);
//               
//             });
//             google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'dragend', function() {
//               updateCurSelText(newShape);
//               
//             });
            google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'bounds_changed', function() {
              
              
              
                deleteInfowindow(infoWindow);
              setSelection(newShape, isNotMarker);
              
//               updateCurSelText(newShape);


            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function() {
              
              setSelection(newShape, isNotMarker);
              deleteInfowindow(infoWindow);
              
            });

            setSelection(newShape, isNotMarker);

          //~ }// end if
        });
        // Clear the current selection when the drawing mode is changed, or when the
        // map is clicked.
        google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'drawingmode_changed', clearSelection);
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', clearSelection);
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('delete-button'), 'click', deleteSelectedShape);
        buildColorPalette();
        //~ initSearch();
        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
         input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */( //var
            document.getElementById('pac-input'));
//         map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(input);
        //
        var DelPlcButDiv = document.createElement('div');
        //~ DelPlcButDiv.style.color = 'rgb(25,25,25)'; // no effect?
        DelPlcButDiv.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
        DelPlcButDiv.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        DelPlcButDiv.innerHTML = 'DEL';
        
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(DelPlcButDiv, 'click', deletePlacesSearchResults);

        // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
        // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
 
        // Bias the SearchBox results towards places that are within the bounds of the
        // current map's viewport.
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
          var bounds = map.getBounds();
          
        }); //////////////////////
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="panel">
      <div id="color-palette"></div>
      <div>
        <button id="delete-button">Delete Selected Shape</button>
      </div>
    <div id="curpos"></div>
    <div id="cursel"></div>
    
    </div>
    
    <div id="map">A</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?  What do you mean by "I would like to count the numerical order/ID of each shape was drawn in each color, especially the rectangle."?  What ID?

Comment: I mean, when I create the first rectangle in blue color, its ID is 1; then I create the second rectangle in blue, its ID is 2; and then I create the third rectangle in blue, its ID is 3. 

And after that, when I create the first rectangle in red color, its ID is 1. That is what I related to "count the ID of each rectangle was drawn in each color" . Plz help me how to solve its :(

Answer (score 0):

After 1 week, I solved myself, here is the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/drawing/drawing-tools.html -->
<!-- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox 
https://gist.github.com/mhewedy/836d88158b8cdc24494fb5f8b402dd53 -->
<html>

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Draw test</title>
    <!-- NOTE: two libraries to load are comma-separated; otherwise last mention of the query string arg overwrites the previous -->
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3.21.5a&libraries=drawing&signed_in=true&libraries=places,drawing"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      #map, html, body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
      }
      #panel {
        width: 150px;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 13px;
        float: right;
        margin: 10px;
      }
      #color-palette {
        clear: both;
      }
      .color-button {
        width: 14px;    
        height: 14px;
        font-size: 0;
        margin: 2px;
        float: left;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      #delete-button {
        margin-top: 5px;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var drawingManager;
      var selectedShape;
      var colors = ['#1E90FF', '#FF0000'];
        var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        var labelIndex = 0;
      var selectedColor;
      var colorButtons = {};
      var counterDomain = 0;
      var counterRelease = 0;

      
      

      
      
      function updateCurSelText(shape) {
        posstr = "" + selectedShape.position;
        if (typeof selectedShape.position == 'object') {
          posstr = selectedShape.position.toUrlValue();
        }
        
        pathstr = "" + selectedShape.getPath;
        if (typeof selectedShape.getPath == 'function') {
          pathstr = "[ ";
          for (var i = 0; i < selectedShape.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
            // .toUrlValue(5) limits number of decimals, default is 6 but can do more
            pathstr += selectedShape.getPath().getAt(i).toUrlValue() + " , ";
          }
          pathstr += "]";
        }
        
        bndstr = "" + selectedShape.getBounds;

        cntstr = "" + selectedShape.getCenter;


        
        
        if (typeof selectedShape.getBounds == 'function')  {

          var tmpbounds = selectedShape.getBounds();
          cntstr = "" + tmpbounds.getCenter().toUrlValue();
          bndstr = "NE: " + tmpbounds.getNorthEast().toUrlValue() + ' <br />'+
          "SW: "+ tmpbounds.getSouthWest().toUrlValue()+' <br />'+
//           "i = "+selectedShape.getElementById++ ;
          "i = "+labelIndex++ % labels.length ;
//           "i = "+selectedShape.getCenter().toUrlValue() ;


        
        var ne = selectedShape.getBounds().getNorthEast();
        var sw = selectedShape.getBounds().getSouthWest();
if (selectedColor == colors[0]){

                var contentString = '<b>Blue Domain-'+counterDomain+'-Lat/Long: </b><br />' +
                      'Center: '+(ne.lat()+sw.lat())/2 + ' , ' + (ne.lng()+sw.lng())/2 +' <br />'+
                      'North-East-corner: '+ ne.lat() + ' , ' + ne.lng() + ' <br />';
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
        infoWindow.setPosition(ne);
     infoWindow.open(map);
        }
        
        
        
        else {

        var contentString = '<b>Red Domain-'+counterRelease+'-Lat/Long: </b><br />' +
                      'Center: '+(ne.lat()+sw.lat())/2 + ' , ' + (ne.lng()+sw.lng())/2 +' <br />'+
                      'North-East-corner: '+ ne.lat() + ' , ' + ne.lng() + ' <br />';
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
        infoWindow.setPosition(ne);
     infoWindow.open(map);
        
        }
        

        }

       
//         curseldiv.innerHTML = bndstr   ;
//         curseldiv.innerHTML = contentString   ;



      }

      
    function deleteInfowindow(infoWindow){
    
        infoWindow.close();
    }
    
    
    
      function clearSelection() {
        if (selectedShape) {
          if (typeof selectedShape.setEditable == 'function') {
            selectedShape.setEditable(false);
          }
          
          selectedShape = null;
        }
      }
      
      
      function setSelection(shape, isNotMarker) {
        clearSelection();
        selectedShape = shape;
        if (isNotMarker)
          shape.setEditable(true);
        selectColor(shape.get('fillColor') || shape.get('strokeColor'));
        updateCurSelText(shape);
        
      }
      
      
      function deleteSelectedShape() {
              deleteInfowindow(infoWindow);
        if (selectedColor == colors[0]){
            if (selectedShape) {
                selectedShape.setMap(null);
                counterDomain = counterDomain -1;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (selectedShape) {
                selectedShape.setMap(null);
                counterRelease = counterRelease -1;
            }
        }
        
      }
      
      
      function selectColor(color) {
        selectedColor = color;
        for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; ++i) {
          var currColor = colors[i];
          colorButtons[currColor].style.border = currColor == color ? '2px solid #789' : '2px solid #fff';
        }
        // Retrieves the current options from the drawing manager and replaces the
        // stroke or fill color as appropriate.

        var rectangleOptions = drawingManager.get('rectangleOptions');
        rectangleOptions.fillColor = color;
        drawingManager.set('rectangleOptions', rectangleOptions);

      }
      
      function setSelectedShapeColor(color) {
        if (selectedShape) {
          if (selectedShape.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE) {
            selectedShape.set('strokeColor', color);
          } else {
            selectedShape.set('fillColor', color);
          }
        }
      }
      
      function makeColorButton(color) {
        var button = document.createElement('span');
        button.className = 'color-button';
        button.style.backgroundColor = color;
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(button, 'click', function() {
          selectColor(color);
          setSelectedShapeColor(color);
        });
        return button;
      }
      
      function buildColorPalette() {
         var colorPalette = document.getElementById('color-palette');
         for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; ++i) {
           var currColor = colors[i];
           var colorButton = makeColorButton(currColor);
           colorPalette.appendChild(colorButton);
           colorButtons[currColor] = colorButton;
         }
         selectColor(colors[0]);
       }
       
      /////////////////////////////////////
      var map; //= new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      // these must have global refs too!:
      var placeMarkers = [];
      var input;
      var curposdiv;
      var curseldiv;
 
      var infoWindow;
      
      

      
      
      
      function initialize() {
      
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { //var
          zoom: 6,//10,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(18.59590640319714,105.37530464062493),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          disableDefaultUI: false,
          zoomControl: true
        });
        curposdiv = document.getElementById('curpos');
        curseldiv = document.getElementById('cursel');

        var polyOptions = {
          strokeWeight: 2.0,
          fillOpacity: 0.35,
          editable: true          
        };
        // Creates a drawing manager attached to the map that allows the user to draw
        // markers, lines, and shapes.

        drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        
          drawingControl: true,

          drawingControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
            drawingModes: ['rectangle'],
          },

          label: labels[labelIndex++ % labels.length],
//           label: labels[labelIndex++],
//           label: labelIndex++,
          rectangleOptions: polyOptions,
          map: map,
//                         selectedShape.setMap(map),
//                   selectedShape.addListener('bounds_changed', showNewRect),
//         infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),

         }
        );
        

             
        
        
        google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
            var isNotMarker = (e.type != google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER);
            // Switch back to non-drawing mode after drawing a shape.
            drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
            // Add an event listener that selects the newly-drawn shape when the user
            // mouses down on it.
            var newShape = e.overlay;
            newShape.type = e.type;
            if (selectedColor == colors[0]){
                counterDomain=counterDomain+1;
            }
            else{
                counterRelease = counterRelease+1;
            }
            

//             google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'drag', function() {
//               updateCurSelText(newShape);
//               
//             });
//             google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'dragend', function() {
//               updateCurSelText(newShape);
//               
//             });
            google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'bounds_changed', function() {
              
              
              
                deleteInfowindow(infoWindow);
              setSelection(newShape, isNotMarker);
              
//               updateCurSelText(newShape);


            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function() {
              
              setSelection(newShape, isNotMarker);
              deleteInfowindow(infoWindow);
              
            });

            setSelection(newShape, isNotMarker);

          //~ }// end if
        });
        // Clear the current selection when the drawing mode is changed, or when the
        // map is clicked.
        google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'drawingmode_changed', clearSelection);
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', clearSelection);
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('delete-button'), 'click', deleteSelectedShape);
        buildColorPalette();
        //~ initSearch();
        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
         input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */( //var
            document.getElementById('pac-input'));
//         map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(input);
        //
        var DelPlcButDiv = document.createElement('div');
        //~ DelPlcButDiv.style.color = 'rgb(25,25,25)'; // no effect?
        DelPlcButDiv.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
        DelPlcButDiv.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        DelPlcButDiv.innerHTML = 'DEL';
        
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(DelPlcButDiv, 'click', deletePlacesSearchResults);

        // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
        // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
 
        // Bias the SearchBox results towards places that are within the bounds of the
        // current map's viewport.
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
          var bounds = map.getBounds();
          
        }); //////////////////////
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="panel">
      <div id="color-palette"></div>
      <div>
        <button id="delete-button">Delete Selected Shape</button>
      </div>
    <div id="curpos"></div>
    <div id="cursel"></div>
    
    </div>
    
    <div id="map">A</div>
  </body>
</html>
```